# How to position div-containers in responsive page layout?

Tags: css, html, css-float

As far as I know, "absolute" tag will not coupe with responsive design of my theme.

If I position my image div container with proper numbers for full width window (and vise versa), it will not float along with other elements if I tighten up my brwoser window .

[image]

[image]

I think it will take a heap load of time before I will figure out myself.

Comment: http://podstrigis.com/test3/  test page

Answer (score 0):

Take off min-width from the image and it will re-size correctly. The min-width is restricting it from re-sizing correctly. To stop it being tiny you can use the min-width just make it less then 700px as that is only a small jump in size. You could also use media queries to make it 70% width at that screen size.

I think this is what you are wanting it to do?

Answer (score 0):

`position: absolute` should rarely be used for page layouts (except for small elements here and there), because it takes elements out of the flow of the document, meaning that other elements can't respond to it.

You can get the effect you want there by floating the dog image to the right and using a "sandbag" effect to push it down through the text. Here is a basic example of how it works:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/uymJI

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style media="all">
.outer {overflow: hidden;}

.wrapper {width: 50%; margin: 0 auto;}

.image {
  float: right;
  margin-right: -600px;
}

.image:before {
  content: " ";
  height: 300px;
  width: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
<div class="outer">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>

        <div class="image"><img src="http://podstrigis.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/1dreamstime_xxl_25491444.png" alt="Dog listening on can phone"></div>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>



        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

EDIT: based on comment below, another (though ultimately inadequate) attempt:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style media="all">
.outer {overflow: hidden;}

.wrapper {width: 50%; margin: 0 auto; }

.ofl {overflow: hidden;}

.image {float: right; margin-right: -600px;}

.map {clear: both; }

.map div {width: 100%; height: 300px; background: green;}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1500px) {
    .image {margin-top: 0;}

    .dog {margin-top: -258px;}

    .spacer {float: right; width: 300px; height: 265px; background: white;}

    .map {margin-top: 258px;}

    .spacer:before {
        content: " ";
        height: 300px;
        width: 1px;
        overflow: hidden; 
        }
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
<div class="outer">
    <div class="wrapper ofl">

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>



        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p><div class="spacer"></div>



        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>

    </div>

    <div class="wrapper dog">
        <div class="image"><img src="http://podstrigis.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/1dreamstime_xxl_25491444.png" alt="Dog listening on can phone"></div>
        </div>
    <div class="wrapper ofl map">
        <div></div>
    </div> 
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ralph, you are a life saver! That almost works exactly like I've desribed above. Can you give a quick look on my test page - http://podstrigis.com/test3/ ? Full-width browser page works exactly like I want it to be, but when I tighten up browser window  I want my puppy pic stick to a map div container (and keep all of the text above) - http://i.imgur.com/KLb6KYw.jpg

Comment: Hehe, I see. Well, that's tough. I've had a go at it, and have posted the code above, but it's not really robust enough for real world use. Someone cleverer will need to solve this.